# Show $0 < f'(x) \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: derivatives, upper-lower-bounds

Given $f(x) = \arctan(e^x)$, then $\displaystyle f'(x) = \frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}$. Clearly, $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Further, I want to show that $f'(x) \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. How might I do this without appealing to a graph of $f'$?

Comment: You might notice that $f'(x) = \frac {1}{2\cosh x}$

Answer (score 5):

$$ \frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}} \leq \frac{1}{2} \Leftrightarrow
2e^x \leq 1+(e^x)^2 \Leftrightarrow
0 \leq (1-e^x)^2$$

**P.S.** By the same trick you can prove that for all $a \in \mathbb R$ you have
$$-\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{a}{1+a^2} \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

You could find the $x$ for which $f''(x)=0$, which happens to be $x=0$, so $f'(x)\leq\frac{1}{2}$. Of course also check that it is a max either by plugging in a value on the left and on the right of $x=0$ or checking out $f'''$ (last one not recommended).

Comment: How are you concluding that $f''(x) = 0$ at $x = 0$ implies that $f'(x) \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @clocktower Because if the derivative of $f'$ is equal to $0$ (and of course check that it is not an inflection point), then it is a maximum (or minimum, but that will follow from checking inflection). Here the maximum $\frac{1}{2}$ at $x=0$ is unique.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the maximum value of  $$\displaystyle f'(x) = \frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}$$  You may take the second derivative and solve for $$f''(x) =0$$

You will that the only critical point  of $ f'(x)$ occurs at $x=0$ which is a local maximum with $f'(0)=1/2,$ which is also an absolute maximum due to its symmetry.

Thus you have $$ f'(x) \leq \frac{1}{2}$$ for all $x$.